# What does %7C11211%7C11206%7C11222 mean from the Google Static Maps?

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I've been reading and re-reading the portion of the Static Maps Developer guide and I am just not comprehending what this portion does:

> %7C11211%7C11206%7C11222

from this:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY&zoom=13&size=400x400&
>   markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222

Like, I get that that URL adds 3 markers of the same style to the map, center being Williamsburg,Brooklyn, NY but I am failing to see how the other markers are placed.

> Each marker descriptor must contain a set of one or more locations defining where to place the marker on the map. These locations may be either specified as latitude/longitude values or as addresses. These locations are separated using the pipe character (|).

I don't see where there is an address or a latitude/longitude values..is it shorthand?

I Googled that line and all over it is people using it to ask *how to create a center marker*, using that as an example, not explaining how the rest of it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222` portion decoded is just `|11211|11206|11222` -- these are just zip codes separated by a pipe.

Although a zip code isn't what you would normally call an "address", in this case you can use it as one since the map just centers the marker inside of that zip code.

If you wanted to use an actual address, you could do something like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Williansburg,+Brookly,+NY&zoom=13&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:blue%7Clabel:S%7CWilliansburg,+Brookly,+NY
```

Or if you really want to make it easy on yourself, use a generator like [this](http://staticmapmaker.com/google/).